# JavaFX getStylesheet().add(path) not allowing me to read from root of maven project

Tags: java, maven, javafx, path

Here is my project structure

```
  DejaVuu
    -- src/main/java
    ---- views 
    ------ basetheme.css
    -- src/test/java
    -- src
    -- basetheme.css
    -- tempfile.css
```

Currently I am trying to read in my css file with

```
view.getStylesheets().add("basetheme.css");
```

But this does not work. However, it works when I use

```
view.getStylesheets().add("views/basetheme.css");
```

I need basetheme.css at the root because that is where
I rewrite the file to after some updates. In other words,
the read and write location should be the same.

Here is the code I call to write to the file:

```
    public String writeToCSS(String css) throws IOException {
        String path_name = "basetheme.css"; // I need this to match read in for getStyleSheet().add
        File temp = new File(path_name); 
        temp.delete();
        temp.createNewFile();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));
        bw.write("some css");
        bw.close();
        
   
        String temp_url = temp.toURI().toString();
        return temp_url; 
    }
```

Now when looking in `writeToCSS` and the following is set

```
String path_name = "basetheme.css";
```

the above writing works. This is to root of project.
The issue is that now I cannot read the stylesheet into
JavaFX from this location.

With that said, I have tried to write the file to

```
String path_name = "/home/ming/eclipse-workspace/DejaVuu/views/basetheme.css";
```

However, I receive an error when doing this

```
java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
    java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
```

Can `File` not be used to write to packages in MavenProjects?

Comment: It appears that the path I copy and pasted from the file itself is the incorrect path. I did not second guess the path generated, but I just realized this and fixed it, and now I can write to there.

Comment: The path you specify is relative to the *classpath*. What's important is what is available at runtime (when the CSS is actually loaded); i.e. what's important is what's in the build, not the source structure. Check the contents of `target/classes` (the default build folder for Maven) or the jar file if you are building a jar file to understand that layout. It's likely that resources in the project that are outside `src/main/java` or `src/main/resources` simply aren't deployed at all (unless you specifically configure Maven to deploy them).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other